# What's the name of the auto indent code?

Tags: indentation, automation

What's the name of that feature that auto indent the code when I press tab (Even fi the indentation is more to the right, the tab "erases" the abundany spaces) and how can I change the size of it?

Comment: C-h k [tab] will tell you what command [tab] calls.

Comment: It can vary by the major (or minor) modes in use. Without knowing which major mode you're using, we can't say anything more than what Dan has mentioned (which in the case of `TAB` will tend to be the first of several indirect steps to find out the command which is *actually* being called...)

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, the behaviour of *tab* changes often depending on the mode you are using.

I suggest you read more how the indentation works in Emacs in the [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentationBasics)

Main variables are:

- **c-basic-offset**: The basic indentation offset in CC Mode, default is 2. For Perl, it is controlled by *cperl-indent-level.*
- **tab-width**: How wide a tab is, default is 8.